# WebApi tests using in memory hosting hang when solution also contains WinForms tests

Tags: asp.net, nunit, asp.net-web-api

I have a solution that contains a number of different projects that include both WinForms and WebApi (RC). I am seeing an issue with WebApi tests hanging when a prior test instantiates a class that derives from `System.Windows.Forms.Form`. You can find a sample solution that demonstrates the problem here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3688049/SampleSolutions/TestSolution.zip

The solution has NuGet package restore enabled so all the dependencies should get pulled down upon build.

If the `var form = new Form1();` call in Class1.cs is not commented out, then the tests will hang (using latest nuget version of nunit). If it is commented out, the tests pass.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Class1.cs**

```cs
[TestFixture]
public class Class1
{
    [Test]
    public void AaaWindowsFormsApp() {
        // If this line is not commented out the BbbTestWebApiApp test will hang.
        var form = new Form1();
    }

    [Test]
    public void BbbTestWebApiApp() {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        var server = new HttpServer(config, new MyMessageHandler());
        var client = new HttpClient(server);

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://localhost/");

        var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;

        Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
    }
}
```

**MyMessageHandler.cs**

```cs
public class MyMessageHandler: DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK));
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

It seems that adding the `RequiresSTA` attribute to the `System.Windows.Forms.Form` tests resolves the issue.

I'm not sure why adding the WebApi in-memory hosting exposed the problem though.

**UPDATE 2**

`RequiresSTA` only seems to help if you are running the tests via the GUI. The console runner still seems to hang.

Answer (score 1):

This really looks like a bug in nUnit's handling of WinForms.

I ran your solution and noticed that:

1. it works if you separate WebAPI and WinForms test methods into
   different classes
2. it works if you run the WinForms test method after the WebAPI test method
3. the tests work perfectly fine with xUnit

If either of these is acceptable for you, I'd do that and not worry about nUnit (perhaps I'm saying that because I do all my work in xUnit :) )

Comment: #1 will not work if the WinForms test class executes first. I may be able to get our test assemblies re-ordered for this case, but that just seems like kicking the can down the road. I'm guessing that a switch to xUnit isn't likely unless I can become a really good salesman! :)

Comment: I posted to the NUnit mailing list. I will wait to see the outcome of that until I accept your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry I can't help anymore - good luck. And consider xUnit ;-)